# Preserving Slope after Changing Axis Limits (ggplot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, aspect-ratio

Here is some hypothetical data:

```
data <- tibble(x=seq(1:20),
               y=c(55, 50, 45, 40, 42.5, 38, 35, 30, 29.5, 27, 
                     25, 23, 20, 15, 14, 12.5, 11, 8, 7, 6))
```

I would like to plot it on a logarithmic scale as such:

```
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10', 
                     limits = c(1,100)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,20, by=1),
                     limits = c(1,20)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 2)

plot
```

[image]

I intentionally set the aspect ratio to 2 (i.e. 2:1 y:x) . I would like to essentially truncate the y-axis to a minimum of 5 and a maximum of 60, however I want to preserve the same scaling factors. I don't want the new plot to have a 2:1 aspect ratio, but rather for it to be a "cropped" version of the full plot with a 2:1 aspect ratio. In other words, I don't want the slope of the line to change. However, when I try to adjust the limits of the y-axis, like below, the aspect ratio of 2:1, rather than the scaling factor (slope), is preserved. Is there any way to get around this? Thanks.

```
plot2 <- plot + ylim(5, 60)


plot2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to preserve the slope of the line, then instead of using `aspect.ratio`, you can use `coord_fixed`, changing only the y limits:

```r
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10', 
                     limits = c(1,100)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,20, by=1),
                     limits = c(1,20)) +
  theme_classic() 

plot + coord_fixed(10)
```

[image]

```r
plot + coord_fixed(10, ylim = c(5, 60))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: How do you know to specify 10 for the ratio?

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier, but in reality I'm trying to preserve the slope from an initially 2:1 y:x axis ratio. I'm not sure how to implement this solution because I first need to establish the 2:1 aspect ratio before limiting the axes. I updated the question to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: @dd_data if you have a log10 y scale that runs from 1 to 100, then under the hood this is a y axis range of 0 to 2. Since the x axis range is 20, then we need a 10:1 aspect ratio to get an approximately square plot. If you want a 1:2 aspect ratio, then the ratio between x axis and y axis would be 2 * x_axis_range / y_axis_range, or approximately 20. As long as you keep the coord_fixed ratio the same, the gradient will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually adjust the plot's dimensions by specifying the height and width using the ggplot function to "crop" the plot while maintaining the scaling factors. For instance:

```
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(5,60), trans='log10') +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,20), breaks = seq(1,20, by=1)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(5, 60)) +
  theme_classic()

plot
```

[image]